# can i use while loop inside another while loop in php

Tags: php

I'm creating a comment system in my project. I want each posted question to have a comment. I was able to post the comment, but I am having a problem displaying all comment to it's respective answers. I was able to display only one row but not the row of the comment. I try to use a while loop nested inside the while that echo's each question, but it hangs. When I use if it only displays the first row of the comment of each question.

So my question is how can I display them all?

```
<div class="answer">
     <?php
     include 'db.php';
       $sql = "select * from answers where questionrid IN(select id from question where id='$qid')";
       $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       if($result){
     while($ro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     ?>

     <div class="a_view">
    <pre>
     <?php

       echo $ro["answer"];
       ?>
     </pre>
       </div>

      <div class="ans_comment">
          <?php
          if($ro["id"]){
          $id = $ro["id"];
          $sqli = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE answerid='$id'";
          $query = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
          $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
          while($row){
            ?>
            <div><?php echo $row["comments"];?></div>
            <?php

          }
          }
          ?>
      </div>
      <div class="add"><div class="coment">add a comment</div> <div id="coment">
      <form class="cform" method="post" action="acomment.php">
      <textarea type="text" name="comment" class="tcomment" placeholder="add your comment here,your is 
      required to give correction or more information about the problem"></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ro["id"]; ?>" name="userid">
        <input type="submit" value="Post your comment">
   </form>
   </div></div>
       <?php
       }
       }else{
          echo "no record";
       }
       ?>

      <?php
       $con->close();
      ?>
```

This is the section that made it hang

```
 while($row){
            ?>
            <div><?php echo $row["comments"];?></div>
            <?php

          }
```

when I use `if`, it only echos one row.

Comment: All what I'm seeing is `php` code, none of which is `JavaScript`!

Comment: The answer, in JavaScript, or in PHP, which is what you've actually shown, is YES.

Make sure that every while() loop has a means to escape (this is generally a counter that increments the variable that while() is testing).  Also ensure (as it appears you have done) that you don't overwrite the variable names in the outer loop when writing the inner loop.

Comment: I'm not seeing a second `while` loop, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You should show the code that you say makes it hang

Comment: sorry its a mistake i added the second while loop

Comment: It's going to hang because `$row` is always set. **HINT** Look at your first call you did to get each database row...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
while($row){
```

do it just like you're doing in the `while` loop above

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

The way you have it now, `$row` is never changing, and therefore always evaluates to `true`, leaving you stuck in your loop.